# Equivalent of item for Object.entries

Tags: javascript

I am using `Object.entries` because I want to use the key and value but I also want access to the whole item. Is it possible to get the parent of key and value as well?

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
  // How to get the parent of key and value ie [key, value];
}
```

Comment: `[ key, value ]` isn’t a “parent”. If you want `[ key, value ]`, use `[ key, value ]` or just don’t destructure. But why would you need this array?

Comment: Thanks, I didnt actually end up needing it but I was curious how it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructure in the first line instead?

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};

for (const entry of Object.entries(object1)) {
  const [key, value] = entry;
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
  console.log(entry);
}
```